# Get current running Task

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task

Is this possible to get current running `Task` and cancel it in other places which there is no access to Task object? Let's say I started a Task in `classA` and I want to cancel it in `classB`, is there anyway to find current Task and cancel it?

Comment: I think the notion of "Current" task doesn't even exist if you don't save that info somewhere in a variable

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no notion of a current `Task`. There are arbitrarily many tasks running at the same time. Even "running" is not well defined. Is `new TaskCompletionSource<object>().Task` running or is it not?

Create a cancellable `CancellationToken` and pass it to the task to make it self-cancel. Pass the underlying `CancellationTokenSource` to the code that wants to cancel.